# Loading GPS information into map and track waypoints?

Tags: qgis, gps, coordinates, import, tracking

I am using QGIS 1.8 in Ubuntu 12.04. I am working with Robot Operating System (ROS) and QGIS simultaneously. My ROS system is connected to LIDAR (sensors) that will publish GPS message so, I could subscribe and print latitude and longitude values continuously in terminal using C++ program.

My next task is to take this latitude and longitude values from terminal and plot it into QGIS map. Then, I want to track waypoints. Can anyone help me to do so?

I don't have any idea as I am new to QGIS. Note that everything should be done without depending to internet connection.

Comment: related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53310/how-to-connect-waypoint-pairs-and-calculate-length

Comment: I have been trying to Connect to gps by usin qgis in differen occations for a period of time. I think my discoveries in this effort is as bad as it could have been. NOT working.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/124457)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/124457)

Answer (score 3):

[Live GPS Tracking](http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/html/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/live_GPS_tracking.html) is a topic which is covered in the QGIS manual. I haven't tried it myself, but if you run into problems, the mailing list should be able to help you.

[image]

Comment: Also http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Gps_units_download_data_and_live_tracking and http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/live_GPS_tracking.html if the link above 404s for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily get a live feed into your qgis for live visualization of a track would be my guess based on a lot of experimentation with a garmin unit.
You can get data out and do a conversion with gpsbabel or some such and import a gpx or shapefile conversion.
You could update a current position on the map however with live tracking but saving a track out put and then loading it from a gpx conversion from a nmea output might be the most direct path. Depends on your usage. On the fly visualization of tracks and routing types of application would probably require looping a log from a postgresql database and updating on the fly, requiring serious programming experience and a lot of exposure to gps data capture science, postgesql, etc. Nontrivial or there would be a lot of examples out there. DNR Garmin can do on the fly with ArcGIS, however, of course that is a different unit and would have different inputs or file formats likely than your hardware.